# Active Directory Password Sync Products

Tags: active-directory

I have a product which has its own repository in SQL DB and it has its own set of users. I would like to synchronize the SQL DB passwords with that of the corresponding Active Directory passwords.

Could anybody suggest me the popular products or tools available for this type of synchronization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to do what you are asking because in order to do this you would need to be able to decrypt/read the windows passwords and given that they are "hashed" this type of thing is impossible.

Comment: @above 
you are right....We can obtain the clear text passwords by writing our own password filter..but that is never a piece of cakewalk since there is every chance of a mess-up in the DC and also the security could be breached easily...that is why am seeking for an external tool or product